# how to use the tortoisesvn commends in vs2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build-process, tortoisesvn

I'm using TortoiseSVN and Visual Studio 2008. Is there any way to update my project's subversion with svn's version in every build?

For example, 1.0.0.[svn's version] -> 1.0.0.12

Comment: TortoiseSVN on its own doesn't really provide you with a way to perform what you're looking for from commandline or batch.
You should probably have subversion command line installed, then follow @CRice's answer.

Also - "svn's version in every build" isn't well defined, although I'm going to guess you mean the latest revision for the directory, again as CRice shows.

Answer (score 0):

If you have nant scripts which run the builds, you can do something like this.

The build script will run this line:

```
svn log c:\yourWorkingDirectory --xml --limit 1
```

Then it will look at the version # generated in a log file such as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log>
<logentry
   revision="12">
<author>someone</author>
<date>2010-08-01T00:00:00</date>
<msg>Last message</msg>
</logentry>
</log>
```

Here is an example nant script for this:

```
 <exec
   program="svn.exe"
   commandline='log "${workingCopyDirectory}" --xml --limit 1'
   output="${workingCopyDirectory}\_revision.xml"
   failonerror="false"/>
 <xmlpeek
   file="${workingCopyDirectory}\_revision.xml"
   xpath="/log/logentry/@revision"
   property="svn.revision"
   failonerror="false"/>
 <echo message="Using Subversion revision number: ${svn.revision}"/>
```

Then update assembly info using that value before using MsBuild

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN ships with a tool named [SubWCRev](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html).
You can use that tool to have it replace keywords in your file(s).